# ¿Cómo leer Mysql en una aplicación desarrollada con Postgresql en ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo una aplicación que desarrollé con Ruby on Rails usando la BD **Postgres** y necesito leer una tabla de una BD en **Mysql** de otra aplicación, lo que necesito es el total de registros de esa tabla en Mysql, de tal modo que creo que no necesito el modelo de esa tabla en Mysql.
¿Alguna idea que me pueda ayudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega una nueva conexión en el archivo *config/database.yml*; ejemplo<sup>1</sup>:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: app_development
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: <%= ENV["APP_DB_USER"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["APP_DB_PASSWORD"] %>

external:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  host: 127.0.0.1
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: <%= ENV["EXTERNAL_DB_USER"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["EXTERNAL_PASSWORD"] %>
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>*Utiliza **host** que corresponda a la BD que quieres conectarte*</sup>

Y luego crea un modelo que se conecte a esa base de datos utilizando `establish_connection`:

```
class ExternalTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection(:external)
  self.table_name = 'mi_tabla'
end
```

Ahora podrás obtener el total de registros como lo harías con cualquier otro modelo:

```
ExternalTable.count
```

Comment: Faltó agregar que hay que instalar la respectiva gema de mysql en el gemfile  gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby